# $watcher count exploding in ng-repeat virtual scolling

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to implement a virtual scrolling tree directive in Angular [using this guide as a reference](http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2014/11/angularjs-virtual-list-directive-tutorial/). However, when I start scrolling, the $watcher count explodes to 17k-20k+ watchers (which crashes the page), scrolling is consistently slow, and nothing I have tried seems to help.

Plunker with my current code: ***[HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/jlDQ8D8MKOGnzuuzdNAR?p=preview)***

(Note, above not showing up for me in Firefox, but is working in Chrome). If you have any thoughts of what else I can try so the scrolling is not a disaster, I am open for ideas. Been working on this for way too long...

**Other methods I have tried:**

`$compile(element.components())(scope.$new())`

Was called in onScroll(). Result: The list no longer displayed at all/still lagged badly and I got continual "Cannot call method 'insertBefore' of null on $compile" errors until the page crashed.

`<li ng-repeat="node in nodeList" vs-node="node"></li>`

Aka, I tried to give each element an isolated scope of its own in hopes that its scope and any watchers associated with it would be destroyed when the list was updated. Result was no difference with the watcher issue of above.

```
function clearVisibleProvider(nodeList){
  for(var i=nodeList.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    nodeList[i] = null;
  }
  return nodeList;

  function clearNode(node){
    if(node.nodes){
      for(var j=node.nodes.length-1; j >= 0; j--){
        clearNode(node.nodes[j]);
      }
    }
    nodeList[i] = null;
   }
}
```

An attempt to clear old list elements before replacing them. Again, no difference. It was called within updateDisplayList() before the main list was updated.

Answer (score 0):

Achieved my goal by redesigning to use a regular list view instead. Displayed nodes are flattened into a list, manual indexing is used to keep track of things, and there is no nesting. Any elements that would be nested have padding calculated based on their level of depth in the tree.

There was also a bug where I was getting too many nodes at once as well. Instead of 50, I'd get 200-500. Fixing that did not solve the watch count exploding however, so I don't consider it the source of the original problem.